# FPDF cell places text somewhere

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, fpdi

I have read already a lot of cases here but nothing of the suggested solutions worked for me so therefore I am asking for some hints/help.
I use FPDI/FPDF with a method to place text in cells, in short it is:

```
public function placeTextCell($font, $fontSize, $x, $y, $red, $green, $blue, $text, $align) {
        $this->pdf->SetFont($font, '', $fontSize);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor($red, $green, $blue);
        $this->pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
        $this->pdf->Cell(0,8,$text,0,0,$align);
    }
```

I am calling this method several times like:

```
$this->placeTextCell('crazy-font',8,5,30,255,255,255,'the text','R');
$this->placeTextCell('crazy-font',8,5,35,255,255,255,'the text','R');
$this->placeTextCell('crazy-font',8,5,40,255,255,255,'the text','R');
.... same with different 'y' coordinate
```

The problem is, that it works nearly for all cells, some cells are dislocated like:

```
             the text
             the text
        the text
    the text
             the text
```

I played around with calling Ln() but it doesn't do anything.
I really have no clue at them moment. Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, trim did it. Funny thing, all strings were trimmed before so I'm wondering where the whitespaces come from...